# Ncurses curs_set(0) tty

Tags: c, ncurses, tty

my question probably has a simple answer (or no answer at all), but what could cause curs_set(0) (make the cursor invisible) to fail on a tty but not on a terminal emulator?

My test code is the simplest possible:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    initscr(); curs_set(0);
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean specifically by a "tty"? Do you mean on the Linux virtual console?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for choosing the wrong word.

Comment: Apparently, this isn't a programming issue, since the cursor also appears in software like htop.

Answer (score 1):

Either the tty lacks the ability to disable the cursor, *or*, the code to disable the cursor is incorrectly defined (or missing) in the terminfo description being used for the tty. Specifically, ncurses tries to use the "civis" capability. You can check how and whether this is defined for your tty via the "infocmp" command.

The answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-to-stop-cursor-from-blinking) include lots of relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

The [**`curs_set`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-curs_set) manpage says:

> The  curs_set  routine  sets  the cursor state to *invisible*, *normal*, or
> *very visible* for visibility equal to 0, 1, or 2 respectively.   If  the
> terminal  supports  the visibility requested, the previous cursor state
> is returned; otherwise, ERR is returned.

The required terminal capabilities are mentioned in the [**`terminfo`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manpage:

```
          cursor_invisible            civis     vi     make cursor
                                                       invisible
...
          cursor_normal               cnorm     ve     make cursor appear
                                                       normal (undo
                                                       civis/cvvis)
...
          cursor_visible              cvvis     vs     make cursor very
                                                       visible
```

The `linux` terminal description, which is usually the default for a Linux virtual console, includes the necessary strings:

```
$ infocmp -1 linux | grep 'c.*vis.*='
        civis=\E[?25l\E[?1c,
        cvvis=\E[?25h\E[?8c,
```

If you have `TERM` set to something else, these capabilities may be absent.  For example:

```
$ infocmp -1 vt100 | grep 'c.*vis.*='
```

finds nothing.